# Program closing thread when button pressed Raspberry Pi

Tags: multithreading

I realize there are similar questions here and I have looked at them, I just can't apply the solutions to my own problem.

I am writing an MP3 player for a Pi using visual studio (C#) on a PC, then using Mono on the Pi to run it.
As Mono does not seem to have an MP3 library (happy to be corrected) my workaround is to use a gui interface to control a command line mp3 player (omxplayer).
I have a working test interface which i ssh across to the Pi from my PC to test each time.

The problem is when I hit Button1 to run it, it works fine in that the mp3 plays.
But as soon as I hit button 2 to send the app the "p" key which should pause the program, it just quit out. Ultimately I will have a bunch of buttons sending key presses to control it like next skip stop etc.
I have tested the functionality from a terminal and it works fine.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

"Oh", Please don't flame me for making procStartInfo  and proc global, I was grasping at straws :)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Button Clicked";
            procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("omxplayer", "/home/pi/Music/Debug/Mutter.mp3 &");
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{p}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jsotola I have been grabbing code snippets all over the place for a couple of days, so none of the many examples describe my exact problem. I have been unable to make the link between them, As for being a Linux problem, as near as I can tell it fails on the Pi end running linux. If this is in the wrong location just say so,

Comment: So are you admin and asking me to remove it or just offering an opinion. Seems like a lot of time spent on a  minor detail.

Comment: just an opinion ... you may get a quicker answer at a site that deals with programming issues in multiple programming languages .... this site is more for questions about the unix/linux system itself